# Golang error handling from function and caller to the terminal

Tags: go, error-handling

I want to ask about best practise of error handling,
Lets assume I've the following function that read file parse it,
which could return two types of errors , when the file not found and the unmarshal failed

```
func Parse(source string) (bma.Bma, error) {
    file, err := ioutil.ReadFile(source + "bma.yaml")
    m := bma.Bma{}
    if err != nil {
        logs.Error("Not able to read the bma file")
        return m, err
    }
    err = yaml.Unmarshal([]byte(file), &m)
    if err != nil {
        logs.Error("Not able to unmarshal the bma file ")
        return m, err
    }
    return m, err
}
```

Now If I call to this function and there is error I printing also this error, the Program is CLI program so I think there is too much error will be printed if case of issue, Is It OK, or there is better approach ?

```
bma ,err := Parse("path")
    if err != nil {
        logs.Error("Error while parsing ")
        return m, err
    }
```

Comment: If you are not going to handle the error in function, then return it to parent function by adding context, like file name if unable to open or read...

Comment: @nilsocket - Can you please provide example ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you are asking is more about when to print errors not when handle or not the errors. In my case I like printing all logs that I can if I think they will be useful for me in future.

In your case maybe the message `logs.Error("Error while parsing ")` is too verbose because you are not showing any details there.

Other approach that you can consider is returning your custom error to the top level functions instead of in the deeper ones and only display the log message there. In the case of the example should be something like this:

```
func main() {
    bma, err := Parse("path")
    if err != nil {
        log.Println(err)
        return
    }
}

func Parse(source string) (bma.Bma, error) {
    file, err := ioutil.ReadFile(source + "bma.yaml")
    m := bma.Bma{}
    if err != nil {
        return m, fmt.Errorf("Not able to read the bma file: %s", err.Error())
    }
    err = yaml.Unmarshal([]byte(file), &m)
    if err != nil {
        return m, fmt.Errorf("Not able to unmarshal the bma file: %s", err.Error())
    }
    return m, err
}
```

Comment: thanks, but the fmt will print the error , If I just what to return it I need use package errors isnt it ? –

Comment: the `fmt` package is for formatting not for printing, in this case the function Errorf (https://golang.org/pkg/fmt/#Errorf) returns an error, that matches with your signature of Parse. If you don't need to format the message (adding the `%s`) you can use the `errors` package with `New()` method https://golang.org/pkg/errors/#New

Answer (score 0):

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "os"
)

func main() {
    fileName := "main.go"
    err := parse(fileName)
    if err != nil {
        log.Println(err)
    }
    log.Println(parse2(fileName))
    log.Println(parse3(fileName))
    //Incase of library one need to create new errors and export them
    //see error.go file of some stdlib packages for some example
}

func parse(s string) error {
    _, err := os.Open(s + "t") // fails
    if err != nil {
        // no need to add any custom err information,
        // as err contains required details (action, fileName, error)
        return err
    }
    return nil
}

func parse2(s string) error {
    // Incase you must handle errors
    _, err := os.Open(s + "t") // fails
    if err != nil {

        err = (err.(*os.PathError)).Err //only, if you must handle it

        if err == os.ErrPermission {
            //send notification to developer, about user
        } else if err == os.ErrNotExist {
            //user is so irresponsible, block him
        } else if os.IsNotExist(err) {
            fmt.Println("found the cause")
        }
        return err

    }
    return nil
}

func parse3(s string) error {
    err := badError(s)
    if err != nil {
        // wrap error with required context information,
        // if err doesn't return proper error
        // or if you have more useful information
        return fmt.Errorf("%s ,%s", s, err)
    }
    return nil
}

func badError(s string) error {
    return fmt.Errorf("badError,I'm not saying why it failed, and what's the argument which caused me to fail, and making error without actually any content")
}
```